# Find line starts with notice and delete it in the text document

Tags: java

I am trying to delete lines from my test document that starts with `public`. I have tried the following but `public` line is not being deleted. How can I fix it?
I appreciate any help.

**Simple:**

```
In less than a week,
public face of FIFA

has gone from something resembling

an old-style Communist Party rally
 to what looks more like a scene from
```

**Code:**

```
try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("D:\\hl_sv\\" + newName);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                if (!line.equals("public")) {

                    writer.println(line);
                    writer.flush();
                }


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: "I have tried the following and it's not working" is not a very useful description, nor does it show any effort investigating the problem. Perhaps you have, but please spend some time explaining your investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `String#startsWith(String str)`:

```
if (!line.startsWith("public")) {
```

`equals` check if the *whole* line is equal to `public`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `equals` method which will return true only if line has only one word i.e. `public`. 
`equals` returns true only if exact match.

You should use `String.startsWith` method instead of equal.

```
line.startsWith("public")
```

Or you can use `String.contains()` if `public` could be anywhere in string

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!line.startsWith("public")) {
    //do work
}
```

you are check if the entire line is equal to string  "public" so if there are any other characters on the line it will not be matched. Need to see if public appears anywhere in the line.